# how to store TimeStamp into db4o database

Tags: java, timestamp, field, db4o, transient

I am trying to store timestamps into a db4o database, but the stored timestamps which store a few mninutes ago are much different from the current date.

Here are example outputs:

```
1969-12-31 19:00:00.741
1969-12-31 19:00:00.772
2012-10-14 00:23:22.713
```

The two previous stored timestamp was stored as 1969-12-31 19:00:00.7xx after I run my code three times.

Here is the code.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded;
import com.db4o.ObjectContainer;
import com.db4o.ObjectSet;
import com.db4o.config.EmbeddedConfiguration;

public class dbTest {

  public static void listResults(ObjectSet<Timestamp> results) {

    for (Timestamp o : results) {
      System.out.println(o);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    EmbeddedConfiguration config = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();
    config.common().objectClass(Timestamp.class).storeTransientFields(true);

    ObjectContainer container = Db4oEmbedded
        .openFile(config, "timestamps.db4o");

    try {

      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      container.store(new Timestamp(now));

      final ObjectSet<Timestamp> results = container.query(Timestamp.class);
      listResults(results);
    }
    finally {
      container.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I read the two pieces of related article below but the issue has not been solved.

[article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014691/storing-an-object-containing-a-calender-object-in-a-db4o-local-database-cannot) and [article 2](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-7.0/java/reference/html/reference/usage_pitfalls/storing_timestamp_and_date_values.html)

Please advise me how to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Should I store timestamp as a String type into the database? Each time  the program need convert the string value into an object of Timestamp after retrieving data from the database.

Comment: I copy this post to the db4o forum at the [page](http://community.versant.com/Forums/tabid/98/aft/12113/Default.aspx#34176). Hope to hear from some answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem by adding a line:

```
config.common().objectClass(Timestamp.class).translate(new TSerializable());
```

I got help from Vidisha & Claude at db4o forum. Here I share the answer, and hope to help other as well. Here is the new code.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;   

import com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded;   
import com.db4o.ObjectContainer;   
import com.db4o.ObjectSet;   
import com.db4o.config.EmbeddedConfiguration;   

public class dbTest {   

  public static void listResults(ObjectSet<Timestamp> results) {   

    for (Timestamp o : results) {   
      System.out.println(o);   
    }   
  }   

  public static void main(String[] args) {   

    EmbeddedConfiguration config = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();   
    config.common().objectClass(Timestamp.class).translate(new TSerializable());   
    ObjectContainer container = Db4oEmbedded   
        .openFile(config, "timestamps.db4o");   

    try {   

      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();   
      container.store(new Timestamp(now));   

      final ObjectSet<Timestamp> results = container.query(Timestamp.class);   
      listResults(results);   
    }   
    finally {   
      container.close();   
    }   
  }   
}
```

You are recommanded to use JDK Date which can be handled properly by db4o.